# Parsing JSON API in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net

so I'm fairly new to programming but am looking to go much deeper with it.  I recently started to get involved in a project to create a WinForm program for a website that uses an API system in JSON.

I've never used an API before so I'm not quite sure how it works  but after looking at it for a few minutes I seem to have the gist of it.  What I don't get is how exactly parsing JSON in C# works.

I found
[this link](http://www.masnun.me/2011/07/08/quick-json-parsing-with-c-sharp.html) after a little google searching.  And I got it working (somewhat) with this code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        WebClient c = new WebClient();
        var vLogin = c.DownloadString("https://www.openraid.us/index.php/api/login/username/password");
        //Returns string 
        //{"status":1,"error":null,"token":"250-1336515541-c48d354d96e06d488d1a2530071ef07c9532da26"} 
        //Token = random, no decisive length*/
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(vLogin);
        Console.WriteLine("Login Status: " + o["status"]);
        String sToken = "" + o["token"];
        Console.WriteLine(sToken);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        //Breaks after this
        var myRaids = c.DownloadString("https://www.openraid.us/index.php/api/myraids/"+sToken);
        JObject r = JObject.Parse(myRaids); //error occurs here
        String sEventId = "" + r["event_id"];
        Console.WriteLine("Event ID: " + sEventId);
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So to me it looks like I have parsing 1 page done and handled, but when I move onto the second I get this error.

> Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.

So I guess my question is, how do I parse more than 1 page or call of JSON and what would be the easiest way to break up each section of the JSON object (Such as `status`, `error`, and `token`, into C# strings?

Comment: From the look of it, the second request is not returning valid JSON. Have you verified that the data returned is what you think it is?

Comment: Well the token never stays the same, but it is valid for 24 hours. I manually opened the API in a browser and got [this](http://pastebin.com/3anJMwsZ) back.  So it looks like valid JSON to me but the error could be in the call to download the string having `sToken` at the end.

Comment: Functionally, your code looks fine; also, the json response you provided seems valid. Is it possible that something else is being returned by your call to DownloadString()? For sanity's sake, try printing out exactly what is returned from that method call without parsing it.

Comment: I'm with Nathan on this.  Write the string `myRaids` out or put a debug on that line just immediately after the `c.DownloadString`.  I pasted your json into http://json2csharp.com/ and it created a valid c# object from it.

Comment: I do an output straight after doing the DownloadString and it works and properly displays the data but I have no idea where you would go after there, how would I break up the String if I can't parse it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Did you try to JArray instead? Depending on what kind of object you are trying to return

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
var data = client.DownloadString("");
var jArray = JArray.Parse(data);
```

Comment: +1 it's probably in the doco somewhere but one would expect the JSON.Net API is a bit more intuitive... thanks for this answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

JSON requires brackets for arrays and commas between multiple objects.

This is [per the JSON standard](http://www.json.org/).  I also recommend using [JSON.net via NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json) instead of the native JSON parser unless it is overkill and you cannot have the extra bloat.

For example, your parsing a file with two seperate JSON objects - the following does not work per the JSON standard (lacks a comma between the 2 objects and the two objects are not encapsulated by brackets):

```
{"status":1,"error":null}
{"status":2,"error":null}
```

The following 3 JSON objects parsed from a file does work (has brackets for multiple objects and commas between objects):

```
[{"glossary": {"title": "fun glossary","SeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
{"glossary": {"title": "grey glossary","SeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]},
{"glossary": {"title": "blue glossary","SeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cut every JSON object(Array) into more object using for loops 
the C# API is System.Json

```
var jsonArray = JsonArray.Parse(st);//st is the string which contain the JSON objects
foreach (var item in jsonArray) {
    JsonObject ob = new JsonObject(item);
    foreach (var t in ob.Values) {
        JsonObject oo = new JsonObject(t);
        foreach (var x in oo) {
            textBox1.AppendText(x.Key + “ : ” + x.Value + “\n”);
        }
    }
}
```